# How to scale an overlay image based on the Google Maps zoom level

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, python-imaging-library, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to paste an overlay image on a static google map screenshot. Here is the code snippet -

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

API_KEY = '***'

plot_center =  [75.49927187059548, 26.613400716542262]

zoom = 18
image_size = "640x480"

# Download Google image
url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={plot_center[1]},{plot_center[0]}&zoom={zoom}&size={image_size}&key={API_KEY}&maptype=satellite"
response = requests.get(url)
google_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))


# Download the overlay image
response = requests.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/kawa-public/4ed05009-8a61-4eb9-8b17-faa8d0d65ae3/kvi/kvi-s2-2023-07-03T15-01-25.838Z.png")
overlay_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))


output_image = Image.new("RGBA", google_image.size)
output_image.paste(google_image, (0, 0))

overlay_position = (
    (google_image.width - overlay_image.width) // 2,
    (google_image.height - overlay_image.height) // 2,
)

output_image.paste(overlay_image, overlay_position, mask=overlay_image)
output_image.save("output_image.png")
```

The current output just pastes the overlay image to the center of the map which -

[image]

I want the overlay image to cover the farm plot in which it is currently in.

Comment: Is the scale of the overlay fixed?  What I mean, if in this overlay, the southern boundary is 500m wide, is the 500m in another overlay the same number of pixels. I.e. are they all proportional?  If all the overlays are to the same scale then you might only need to find the right value for `zoom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps uses a Mercator projection, so it uses this formula:

`meters_per_pixel = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, zoom)`

We can deduct from this formula that for a given location, the only variable is the zoom, and therefore the meters per pixel are inversely proportional to `2^zoom`.

You can figure out a correct factor of the size of your overlay image for a given zoom (let's say 18 for precision), then divide that factor by 2 for each unzoom operation.

With some trial and error, I found that `3.8` is a correct overlay zoom factor for a zoom of 18, then you can divide it by 2 for each zoom less, giving this code:

```py
# ...
overlay_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
factor = 3.8 / (2 ** (18 - zoom))
overlay_image = overlay_image.resize(
    (int(overlay_image.width * factor), int(overlay_image.height * factor))
)
# ...
```

Comment: I get a tuple error when trying to implement your answer in the OP's code.  Can you show how `overlay_image` is implemented correctly in the OP's code?

Comment: there should not be any error with this, did you copy paste it right?
You just need to add my code (the factor line and the one below which resizes) after the OP's line `overlay_image = Image.open(...)`

Comment: It works now.  Is there anyway not to a *trial and error* approach beyond machine learning?

Comment: It depends what overlay do you want to have. I can't find a reasonable reason why it'd require using machine learning. If you've got an overlay to put on a map that is EXACTLY the shape of a field, that's already very specific to place.
Let's say you do have that overlay, how do you know approximately where to place it? you must have some coordinates, but if you have them then problem solved..

Your question seems much beyond the scope of OP's question and hardly imaginable

Comment: My thoughts center on the numbers of images that might require to be overlaid. One image is easy, but hundreds is not so easy to guess. This is why I asked the OP for additional information about their use case.

Comment: what they seemed to want is rather that the overlay automatically gets to the correct size no matter the zoom

Answer (score 2):

Since you specified the **zoom level** and **map image size** as hard-coded values, you can only scale your overlay image with an equally hard-coded scale factor:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

API_KEY = '***'

plot_center =  [75.49927187059548, 26.613400716542262]

zoom = 18
image_size = "640x480"

# Download Google image
url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={plot_center[1]},{plot_center[0]}&zoom={zoom}&size={image_size}&key={API_KEY}&maptype=satellite"
response = requests.get(url)
google_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))


# Download the overlay image
response = requests.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/kawa-public/4ed05009-8a61-4eb9-8b17-faa8d0d65ae3/kvi/kvi-s2-2023-07-03T15-01-25.838Z.png")
overlay_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
scale_factor = 4  # This is the hard coded scale factor.
overlay_image = overlay_image.resize((overlay_image.width * scale_factor, overlay_image.height * scale_factor), resample=Image.Resampling.NEAREST)

output_image = Image.new("RGBA", google_image.size)
output_image.paste(google_image, (0, 0))

overlay_position = (
    (google_image.width - overlay_image.width) // 2,
    (google_image.height - overlay_image.height) // 2,
)

output_image.paste(overlay_image, overlay_position, mask=overlay_image)
output_image.save("output_image.png")
```

The result obtained is:

[image]

**Note:** Suppose your **map image size**, **overlay image size**, **zoom level**, and **overlay image location** in the map are dynamic. In that case, you should dynamically guess the scale factor and overlay offset (top and left in the map image) by image processing or machine learning techniques.

Comment: If the mentioned **Note** in my solution is applicable to your problem, please let me know so that I can provide a new solution utilizing image-processing tools to dynamically extract the **scale factor** and **overlay image location**.

Comment: I had to replace `Image.Resampling.NEAREST` with `Image.NEAREST`. I'm using version `10.0 of Pillow`.  What version did you use to get this `Image.Resampling.NEAREST`?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I have used `Pillow==9.5.0`. I have rechecked and confirmed that both `Image.Resampling.NEAREST` and `Image.NEAREST` are functioning correctly and yield the same results. You can confirm that [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#filters).